# Событие jQuery - значение выбранного элемента Input

Tags: jquery, события

http://jsfiddle.net/5tYz2/6/

По клику на слой **Click here**, alert возвращает вместо целочисленного значения выбранного элемента Input, текст **On**

Comment: не нашел причины такого поведения, однако можно использовать `.attr('val')` в качестве workaround-a. А еще там сразу четыре чекнутых радио.  
upd бггг вот я слепой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы неправильно написали атрибут val в инпуте. нужно value.

http://jsfiddle.net/5tYz2/7/

Answer (score 3):

У вас у инпутов неправильно задан атрибут value

```
<input name="lang" type="radio" val="153" checked="checked">
```

Исправьте везде val на value, заработает http://jsfiddle.net/5tYz2/15/